# Batch won't recognize an existing variable?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, environment-variables, batch-processing, hybrid

I'm working on a little experiment, where I have a batch file output the contents of the environmental variables `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` into a text file. A visual basic script will then read the files, and pick out a specific part of the file text based off of a pattern, and output THAT into a separate text file. The batch file will then read THAT file and import it as a variable. Here's the code:

```
:load
@echo off
if exist date.txt DEL date.txt
if exist time.txt DEL time.txt
if exist dateextracted.txt DEL dateextracted.txt
title Testing
color 0a
goto start

:start
echo %DATE%> date.txt
echo %time%> time.txt
echo. > dateextracted.txt
START date.vbs
goto wait1

:wait1
if exist dateextracted.txt goto wait2
goto wait1

:wait2
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (dateextracted.txt) do (
set dateextracted=%%a
)
echo %dateextracted%
pause
exit
```

Now the problem is that the batch file just says "ECHO is off." This means that the batch file doesn't see anything in the variable `%dateextracted%`, even though the variable DOES exist, and there IS stuff in it. For example, as of posting this thread, the date is 12/27/2018. So, the variable should be filled with 12/27/2018. If I open up the text file that the visual basic script outputted, it says 12/27/2018. So there's no problem with the visual basic script, it's just the batch file. I don't know if I'm importing the contents of the text file incorrectly, or if it's just a syntax error.

Comment: I don't see anything related to hybrid, nor vbscript code. To run your vbs don't use start but `wscript.exe/cscript.exe`. @double-beep delayedexpansion is needed when setting **AND** using a variable inside the same/or nested (code block).

Comment: Replace `START date.vbs` by `%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe "%~dp0date.vbs"` and delete the lines from `goto wait1` to `:wait2` and your batch file might work as expected by you.

Comment: @Mofi I don't really understand anything you just said, but I tried `%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe "%~dp0date.vbs"`, and it works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may seem surprising, but your batch script doesn't recognize the variable `%dateextracted%` because it actually does not exist.

`echo. > dateextracted.txt` already creates the file `dateextracted.txt`, so your `:wait1..goto wait1` loop immediately skips to `:wait2`. However, since `START date.vbs` is running the VBScript asynchronously in the background that script most likely has not finished yet when your `for` loop is reading `dateextracted.txt`. In that situation the loop is reading an empty file and thus doesn't define the variable `%dateextracted%`. This in turn causes the subsequent `echo` command to display the echo status, because the command is invoked without an argument due to the undefined variable.

You can fix the issue by running `date.vbs` synchronously by using the `cscript.exe` interpreter instead of the default `wscript.exe`. Change this:

```
echo. > dateextracted.txt
START date.vbs
goto wait1

:wait1
if exist dateextracted.txt goto wait2
goto wait1

:wait2
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (dateextracted.txt) do (
set dateextracted=%%a
)
```

into this:

```
echo. > dateextracted.txt
cscript.exe //NoLogo date.vbs

for /f "Delims=" %%a in (dateextracted.txt) do (
    set "dateextracted=%%a"
)
```